# How to UN-override master page items with InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I just learned with master pages, you can override items by pressing control, shift and left click the item.  Or you can use this option on a page:

[image]

But how do you selectively prevent items from being override-able after it has been override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Adobe ID help:

> To remove master overrides from one or more objects, select objects
>   that were originally master items. In the Pages panel, target a spread
>   and choose Remove Selected Local Overrides in the Pages panel menu.
>
> To remove all master overrides from a spread, in the Pages panel,
>   target the spread (or master spread) from which you want to remove all
>   master overrides. Choose Edit >Deselect All to make sure that no
>   objects are selected. In the Pages panel, choose Remove All Local
>   Overrides in the Pages panel menu.

**Note:** if you've not over-ridden, but rather detached items, this will not work. If that is the case, you'll have to delete your detached items and re-apply the Master to those spreads.